# Installation stuck at "Retrieving file 43 of 93"

Tags: system-installation

Im trying to install 11.10 from a USB drive.  The installation process starts like it should but it gets to where it reads "Retrieving file 43 of 93" and it stays there.  It's been there for over 15 minutes now with no change.  Tried loading form CD with same issue.

Comment: Isn't there the ``skip`` button to skip retrieving files from the web? If it is, but you cannot click it, try clicking it before it freezes. Skip the operation when it starts at "retrieving file 1."

Comment: have you tried to install ubuntu without network connection? you can install that packages later after you finished the installation process

Comment: Had the same problem and disconnecting the Network Adapter solved it.

Answer (score 7):

If you have this problem installing inside of **VMWare** (I am using Fusion), then simply disconnect the network adapter in the VM.  That immediately allowed my installation to continue.

In **Oracle VM VirtualBox**:

[image: disconnecting network adapter in VirtualBox]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot showing how to do this?

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I was using Oracle VM Virtual Box

Answer (score 4):

If you encounter this problem. Before installing uncheck "Check For Updates" and please disconnect your internet connection

[image: Unchecking Updates]

After the system reboots, use Update Manager to install the latest updates or run `sudo apt-get update&&sudo apt-get upgrade` in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect your Computer from the Internet (pull out the cable) and start the installation a second time. When done, reconnect to the Internet → install system updates as usually ...

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem but I wasn't able to install after unchecking the *Check For Updates* option. I have tried the following way and managed to install after that:

1. Insert CD and select *Try Ubuntu* option.
2. Now check if the Internet is working or otherwise, to ensure there is no problem with the Internet connection.
3. Select the option *Install Ubuntu* in the desktop during live session.

After that, you should now be able to install without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "Cancel" option to proceed.  It'll most likely then skip the immediate culprit file and proceed to the next.

You could in conjunction with this do some of the other answers such as disconnect the NIC (for the VM's remove the configured NCI).

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem on a new laptop while installing 16.04LTS. It would stop at file 40, or more often 68. Depending on whether Downloading updates was picked. Found inspiration in the following article:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

In short:- disable secure boot AND uefi in the bios. Then fresh install.

(hardware was Intel Pentium Quad + Integrated HD Graphics)